# JBoss Fuse Vs JBoss ESB - can find good info

Tags: jboss-esb

I does anyone have a short explanation on the diff between JBoss Fuse and JBoss ESB. ?

What will I gain by using JBoss ESB ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

look this one:

[SOA with RedHat what to choose ? JBoss ESB ? JBoss FUSE ? JBoss  switchyard ?](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/229838?tstart=0)

JBoss ESB is currently and will continue to be supported as part of SOA Platform 5.  For SOA Platform 6, JBoss ESB will be replaced by SwitchYard.  SOA Platform 6 shares many key elements with Fuse, including support for Apache Camel, CXF, and ActiveMQ.  All of these projects will be active on the community front as they are all supported in products offered by Red Hat and will be for some time.

There were a number of sessions at Red Hat Summit this year which talked about alignment and roadmap for Red Hat integration.  The slides should be available soon here:
http://www.redhat.com/summit/2013/presentations/

Answer (score 0):

JBOSS ESB has reached the EOL.

Our customer now using JBOSS FUSE 6.0, but they have an issue with a simple webservice proxy...

Upgrading to JBOSS Fuse 6.1 may help, but it is very different from 6.0

I think the best choice if you start with microservice architecture.